# How to create UI like TorchLight. eg. FlashLight Zaphrox

Tags: android

I am working in camera flash application.

I am able to start and stop the camera LED. 
I am having problemregarding GUI designing of Torch light.

I want to create GUI like [FlashLight Zaphrox](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zaphrox.android.flashlight.maclight&feature=related_apps)..

What i guess is :

You can see that when torch button is clicked, the image changes. View only changes when torch button is clicked.

What i tried so far is :

```
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        width = display.getWidth();
        height = display.getHeight();

        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageId);

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {

                Toast.makeText(ImageClicker.this,me.getRawX()+" "+me.getRawY(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.i("View--Width & Height",view.getWidth()+" "+view.getHeight());
                Log.i("View -- Measured Width & Height",view.getMeasuredWidth()+" "+view.getMeasuredHeight());
                Log.i("Simple X Y Coordiantes",me.getX()+" "+me.getY());
                Log.i("Raw Coordinates",me.getRawX()+" "+me.getRawY());
                Log.i("Display Matrix",width+" "+height);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

& the results i got for two different sized emulators are :

For 320x480

```
09-07 16:32:28.439: INFO/View--Width & Height(2305): 320 43
09-07 16:32:28.439: INFO/View -- Measured Width & Height(2305): 320 43
09-07 16:32:28.449: INFO/Simple X Y Coordiantes(2305): 160.0 21.0
09-07 16:32:28.449: INFO/Raw Coordinates(2305): 160.0 264.0
09-07 16:32:28.449: INFO/Display Matrix(2305): 320 480
```

For 480x800

```
09-07 16:33:22.454: INFO/View--Width & Height(410): 480 64
09-07 16:33:22.464: INFO/View -- Measured Width & Height(410): 480 64
09-07 16:33:22.474: INFO/Simple X Y Coordiantes(410): 240.0 31.0
09-07 16:33:22.474: INFO/Raw Coordinates(410): 240.0 437.0
09-07 16:33:22.505: INFO/Display Matrix(410): 480 800
```

### Edited

Tried according to incrediApp's answer : [Code](http://www.pastebin.com/1rGAEyrF). 
But no result yet.

I dont know how to handle such click events.

I want to have the same UI as of [Flashlight Zaphrox](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zaphrox.android.flashlight.maclight&feature=related_apps).

I want to create the same effect in my application.
How can i do that ? Better if one can explain with example.

Comment: Check [this class](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/FractionalTouchDelegate.java) from Google IO 2011 app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a canvas that catches touch event in particular area(called flag) like -

```
public class CustomView extends View{

    private int mFlagX = -1;
    private int mFlagY = -1;
    private Bitmap mBitmap = null;
    private Paint mPaint = null;
    private boolean isFlagHidden = false;
    private int mBoundX = -1;
    private int mBoundY = -1;

    //play with these values to listen the click more closer to flag
    public final int CLOSER = 50;
    public final int CLOSE = 100;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet aSet) 
    { 
        super(context, aSet); 
        //load our bitmap (flag image)
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.transperent);
        //create a paint brush
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        //initialize
        if ((mFlagX < 1) || (mFlagY < 1)) {

                   //adjust these values for listening area
                    mFlagX = (int) (getWidth() / 2) - mBitmap.getWidth()/ 2 ;
            mFlagY = (int)getHeight() / 2) - mBitmap.getHeight() / 2 ;
            mBoundX = (int)getWidth() - mBitmap.getWidth();
            mBoundY = (int)getHeight() - mBitmap.getHeight();
        }
        //draw background
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), mPaint);
        //draw the flag
        if (!isFlagHidden) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mFlagX, mFlagY, null);
        }
    }

    public void hideTheFlag()
    {           
        isFlagHidden = true;
        //force redraw
        invalidate();   
    }

    public void giveUp(){
        isFlagHidden = false;
        //force redraw
        invalidate();
    }   

    public int takeAGuess(float x, float y)
    {   

        //this is our "pretty closer" area
        Rect prettyClose = new Rect(mFlagX - CLOSE, mFlagY - CLOSE, mFlagX+mBitmap.getWidth() + CLOSE, mFlagY+mBitmap.getHeight() + CLOSE);
        //normalize
        if (prettyClose.left < 0) prettyClose.left = 0;
        if (prettyClose.top < 0) prettyClose.top = 0;
        if (prettyClose.right > mBoundX) prettyClose.right = mBoundX;
        if (prettyClose.bottom > mBoundY) prettyClose.bottom = mBoundY;

        //this is our "really closer" area
        Rect reallyClose = new Rect(mFlagX - CLOSER, mFlagY - CLOSER, mFlagX+mBitmap.getWidth() + CLOSER, mFlagY+mBitmap.getHeight() + CLOSER);
        //normalize
        if (reallyClose.left < 0) reallyClose.left = 0;
        if (reallyClose.top < 0) reallyClose.top = 0;
        if (reallyClose.right > mBoundX) reallyClose.right = mBoundX;
        if (reallyClose.bottom > mBoundY) reallyClose.bottom = mBoundY;

        //this is the area that contains our flag
        Rect bullsEye = new Rect(mFlagX , mFlagY , mFlagX+mBitmap.getWidth(), mFlagY+mBitmap.getHeight());

        //check to see where on the board the user pressed
        if (bullsEye.contains((int) x, (int)y)) {
            //found it
            isFlagHidden = false;
            invalidate();
            return 1;
        } else if (reallyClose.contains((int) x, (int)y)) {
            //really closer
            return 2;
        } else if (prettyClose.contains((int)x, (int)y)) {
            //pretty closer
            return 3;
        } else {
            //far away
            return 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your activity,override onTouch() for listening to the touch on flag -

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    if (v.getId() == R.id.the_canvas)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            if (isFlagHidden) 
            {
                switch (mCustomView.takeAGuess(event.getX(), event.getY()))
                {
                   case 1:
                         mCustomView.giveUp();  

                          /*
                             YOUR CODE GOES HERE
                          */
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bull's eye", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  

                         break;
                    case 2:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "really closer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 3:                 
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pretty closer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "far away", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Reference: [Capture the flag: A tutorial on Android’s Canvas class and Touch event handler](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/capture-the-flag-a-tutorial-on-androids-canvas-class-and-touch-event-handler/403)

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom view, override onTouchEvent and check the coordinates.

Comment: can you provide me any sample for that ?

Comment: In the API Demos project you have a class called ColorPickerDialog. It has everything you need...

Comment: In `ImageView` i am getting `MotionEvent` object inside `onTouch()` & in `onTouchEvent()` of custom `View` also i am getting `MotionEvent` object.. & coordinate results are same. Whats the difference ?

Comment: It's probably the same event. If you handle the event in the upper layer (custom view) and return true to signify that the event was handled, it won't propogate to the image view.

Comment: From `MotionEvent` i can get device X and Y coordinates (eg when user clicks on the screen or my image shown in canvas). And this will vary with Display size of the device. How can i get which portion of image was clicked ?. Where sholuld i implement my own coordinate system ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing onTouch of Custom view you can use the RelativeLayout and place the button on ImageView like this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/exit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

check with the different resolution

here are the images are used in this layout.

[main image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C0fd.png)

[button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biQye.png)